# Development tools for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am from an asp.net background and I am using the Visual Studio & TFS to build the web applications. Now I want to start a new SharePoint project, so what are the required development tools if I need to write some code to extend SharePoint or develop web parts?
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

What version of SharePoint do you plan to use?
First of all, in general to develop for SP you need SP installed on the local computer. In addition to it, you have to install developer tools for VS.

If you plan to use SP2010, you can use [this script](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23415). It will install all what you need (including SP) on your computer.

If you plan to develop for SP2013, you should install it, VS2012 and [Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627.aspx)

Comment: i am planning to use the latest version of SP 2012.

Comment: Another question , if i buy enterprise SharePoint 2012 will i get all the development tools with it, or i need to buy them separately ?

Comment: The latest version of SP is 2013 RTM (not 2012). Unfortunately, I am not sure about licensing as my employer do it for me, but I think, MS Office development tools are free, but you have to buy VS2012. Anyway, please, don't rely on this answer as it is only my guess.